# Polymer paper-input validity flag

Tags: javascript, validation, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I'm experimenting with Polymer elements and currently with the paper form elements.

I haven't still managed to find if it is possible to get in a Javascript variable the fact that a paper-form is valid. Any ideas?

I'm using auto-validate.

```
 <paper-input id="foo"
        name="foo"
        label="Foo"
        required
        auto-validate
        pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]+"
        error-message="Alphanumerical characters only">
 </paper-input>
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property on the `paper-input` element called `invalid` which you can check to see if the value of the input is valid or not.

For example:

```
<paper-input id="foo"
  name="foo"
  label="Foo"
  required
  auto-validate
  pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]+"
  invalid="{{invalid}}"
  error-message="Alphanumerical characters only">
</paper-input>
```

And then in the JavaScript you can call

```
var invalid = this.$.foo.invalid;
```

See the docs [here](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input/v1.1.24/elements/paper-input#property-invalid) for more info.